# Visual Studio 2017 - Conditional column visibility based on month of year

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a report that has columns 1 - 31 (column is called 1 for day 1, day 30 for day 30...) that are populated with production values for each day of the month.  It's a monthly report, so a month and year is entered and the data is shown by day.  Pretty straight forward, data is from a SQL stored procedure that uses a pivot.

If each month had 31 days, this wouldn't be an issue...but of course we have 30 day months and the users would like to hide day 31 for months with only 30 days.  My visual studious is weak at best, but the developer previous to me did this:

```
=IIF(InStr("2,4,6,9,11", Parameters!Month.Value) > 0,True,False)
```

This works for everything but January...mostly because I know that isn't parsing out the values between the comma's and only looks to see if that digit is in the list...since 1 is in 11, Jan 31 is being dropped when it shouldn't.

1. What should I be using instead of inSTR?
2. Is there a better method than this? It seems hacky to me.

Bonus points - any idea how to hide column 29 for feb except when a leap year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best long term solution for this would be to have a dates table. There are plenty of scripts around to generate one such as https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Then you SP or dataset query uses the date table as the primary table and have left joins to your actual data. Something like

```
SELECT a.* 
    FROM myDateTable d 
        LEFT JOIN myActualTable a on d.date = a.date
    WHERE a.date BETWEEN @myStartDate AND @myEndDate
```

.. you get the idea...

Then in SSRS use a matrix control and add a column group for date. This way you don't need to do anything with visibility as the columns simply won't get generated in the first place.

The advantage of this is it also helps with future queries/reports etc.

**EDIT** I just noticed you said you SP pivots the data. Don't pivot the data, let SSRS take care of that, it's much easier.